# Collapse regexp matches within a line

Tags: code-folding, hideshow

Is there a way I can collapse/expand **regexp matches within a line?**

e.g. let's say I have this list and want to hide some parts of it temporarily:

```
* apple: fruit; red
* butter: dairy; yellow
```

when I set the regexp to ":.*$" and fold the matches, it should become something like this:

```
* apple...
* butter...
```

when I set the regexp to ":.***;" instead**, and fold the matches, it should become something like this:

```
* apple... red
* butter... yellow
```

And when I expand the list, it should get back to the original view:

```
* apple: fruit; red
* butter: dairy; yellow
```

However, none of the methods I found so far doesn't seem to work this way.

I tried *folding mode*, but it only worked for blocks of text, and **it didn't work for string within a line.**

i.e. it doesn't work when I set it to hide things between ":" and ";" below. It doesn't do anything in that case. It only kind of works (but not really appropriately for my purpose) when I set it to hide things between ":" and ":" since they are placed across the lines.

When I try to hide things between ":", this

```
* apple: fruit; red
* butter: dairy; yellow
```

becomes this:

```
* apple: fruit; red...
: dairy; yellow
```

(It might be not exactly like this: I tried this yesterday and I don't remember exactly except that it didn't work fine.)

I also tried *hs-hide-all* with text like "{this should be hidden}" in both org mode and emacs lisp mode, but it didn't do anything. Is this function known to be tricky or something? I'm not even sure if this function is supposed to work for hiding text **within a line** not across lines, or I'm misusing it.

Comment: What is the result you want?  The first example you gave looks good to me.

Comment: @blujay, does my example look like I already achieved that? I meant the example to be something I want to achieve, I'll edit it.

Comment: The problem is that, instead of showing the actual results of what you tried, you simply say, "However, none of the methods I found so far doesn't seem to work this way."  Try this: 1. Show the starting condition.  2.  Show the desired result.  3.  Show what you tried.  4.  Show the actual result.  For more, I suggest reading this: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Comment: @blujay, thanks for pointing that out. I edited it.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear.  Try starting over, write in a very ordered way, in sequence, and be as concise as possible.  Also, use code tags to make strings and regexps clear.  And it would be very helpful if you would paste in the actual elisp code that you're running so we can reproduce exactly what you're doing.